# How can I access part of a tuple which is returned from a custom tag in a Django template?

Tags: django, tuples, django-custom-tags

I have a function that returns a non-current user's first and last name as a tuple, using the following custom tag, where foo is a username from active directory:

```
{% name foo %}
```

I would like to access the first element of the tuple, and the only syntax I could think of is:

```
{{ {% name foo %}.0 }}
```

which is incorrect. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. If your tag is simply returning a value, there's no way to get the first part of it.

Instead, write an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags), which sets a variable in the context. Then you can do this:

```
{% name foo as bar %}
{{ bar.0 }}
```